# Insert Into Multiple Values (Oracle SQL Developer)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a simple insert into statement using multiple values. The solutions I've seen say to separate each set of values with a comma, however, I am still being met with an error. Here is my SQL statement.

```
INSERT INTO DIVISION (DIVISION_ID, DIVISION_NAME)
VALUES ('20', 'Quebec'), ('30', 'Ontario');
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 5):

You can also use this one:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO DIVISION (DIVISION_ID, DIVISION_NAME) VALUES (20, 'Quebec')
  INTO DIVISION (DIVISION_ID, DIVISION_NAME) VALUES (30, 'Ontario')
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

If DIVISION_ID is a numeric data type:

```
INSERT INTO DIVISION (DIVISION_ID, DIVISION_NAME)
SELECT 20, 'Quebec' FROM DUAL  
UNION ALL
SELECT 30, 'Ontario' FROM DUAL;
```

Otherwise:

```
INSERT INTO DIVISION (DIVISION_ID, DIVISION_NAME)  
SELECT '20', 'Quebec' FROM DUAL    
UNION ALL  
SELECT '30', 'Ontario' FROM DUAL;
```